# Как подставить ключ в переменную цикла Twig из внешнего цикла

Tags: twig

У шаблонизатора на входе 2 массива.

[image: массив групп]

---

[image: массив объединенных массивов модемов]

У них есть пересекающийся ключ по которому я хочу их "сцепить". Один массив это группы. Второй многомерный массив это сами модемы которые сгруппированы по этим группам. (ключ idGroup равен ключу в массиве модемов).На месте ХХХХ должен быть этот ключ.

```
{% for idGroup, groupInfoArray in ModemsAndGroup.arrayGroups %}
    {% for key, paramArray in ModemsAndGroup.arrayModems.XXXX  %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Если напрямую его подставлять не работает.

```
{% for idGroup, groupInfoArray in ModemsAndGroup.arrayGroups %}
    {% for key, paramArray in ModemsAndGroup.arrayModems.idGroup %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

А явно если указать то работает

```
{% for idGroup, groupInfoArray in ModemsAndGroup.arrayGroups %}
    {% for key, paramArray in ModemsAndGroup.arrayModems['3504']  %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Как заставить увидеть подставляемый айди группы в голове фора?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил вот так. Все намного проще оказалось)

```
{% for idGroup, groupInfoArray in ModemsAndGroup.arrayGroups %}
    {% for key, paramArray in ModemsAndGroup.arrayModems[idGroup]  %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```